# JavaScript importing module confusion

Tags: node.js

When I am importing 'http' module, I use

```
Var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req,res){......
}.listen(8080)
```

But when I am importing express module, I use

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req,res)=>{........
}
app.listen()
```

Why do I need to create `const app = express();` but not `const app = http();` in the code?

Comment: Because express has a constructor and http does not. It's unrelated to importing

Answer (score 3):

None of your question really has anything to do with importing.

When you do this:

```
const app = express();
```

You are creating an instance of the Express class.  The `express` function is a factory function that creates an object when you call it (in this case it's a function object).  It is not an http server.  It is a both a parent object for a bunch of methods and the main request handler for routing incoming http requests.

When you then do:

```
app.listen()
```

That creates your http server.  In fact, the code inside the `.listen()` method just creates the http server for you and registers `app` as the request handler for incoming connections.

If you look at the [code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L616) for `app.listen()`, you will just see this:

```
app.listen = function listen() {
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

Which just creates an http server instance with the `app` function/object as the main request handler and then it calls `.listen()` to start the server.

So, `app.listen()` is just a shortcut.  You could have used the `http` module yourself to create your own server object and then registered your `app` object with it, but `app.listen()` just does that for you.

---

As a teaching alternative, there are lots of other ways to arrange the code.  You could also do this:

```
const express = require('express');       // load express module
const app = express();                    // create express instance
const http = require('http');             // load http module
const server = http.createServer(app);    // create http server
                                          // and register express listener
server.listen(80);                        // start http server
```

This would not take advantage of the shortcut in `app.listen()`, but would work the same.

Comment: thanks, if express is a class, then why is there no "new" in const app = express(); like const app = new express();

Comment: @Aakash - As I said, the `express()` function is a factory function.  It creates an instance of the object itself.  It does the `new` inside that function.  It does not expose the class constructor directly.  Instead, you call the factory function to get a new instance of the class.  That is one design pattern for creating a new instance of some class.  It is probably implemented this way because Express existed before Javascript had the `class` syntax, but there are other reasons for occasionally preferring a factory function.

Answer (score 1):

`express` exports a function from the module.  `http` exports an object that has functions.

Every library author chooses their own way to export their library.

Here is an example of how they are implemented.

```js
module.exports = function() {
 // code here
 return {
   // calling the function returns an object
 }
}
```

```js
module.exports = {
  createServer() {
  }
}
```